# Download Secure / SSL Heroku PG Backups?

Tags: heroku

When you run heroku pgbackups:url, an Amazon S3 HTTP url is generated. It appears that if you download the database dump it will be sent in the clear? Is there anyway to download it via SSL?

Are pgbackups safe to download in the clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can put an `s` in between the `http` and the `://` yourself.